# add one column under another and assign a group to it

Tags: r, dataframe

My data.frame

```
structure(list(a = c("12", "asd", "zxc", "123"), b = c("45", 
"qwe", "curced", "64"), c = c("78", "tyu", "454", "76")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I would like to add one column under the other and assign and assign groups to the columns. For example, for the first column "1" for the second front "2" for the third moved "3", etc. I know how to transfer columns one under another, but I do not know how to assign groups to them

What I want to get:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R approach using `Map`

```
result <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, a = df, group = seq_along(df)))
```

Another approach using `tidyverse` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'group') %>%
  mutate(group = match(group, unique(group))) %>%
  arrange(group)

#   group value 
#   <int> <chr> 
# 1     1 12    
# 2     1 asd   
# 3     1 zxc   
# 4     1 123   
# 5     2 45    
# 6     2 qwe   
# 7     2 curced
# 8     2 64    
# 9     3 78    
#10     3 tyu   
#11     3 454   
#12     3 76
```

Comment: do not tell me how this can be done in pairs. those 1-2,1-3, and so on?

Comment: I mean a combination of columns

Comment: Sorry, your example and expected output did not contain such combinations. I added an answer based on what is explained in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, here a two different approaches

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### 1-) Comparing name to vector letters

Here I compare each `name` to their position in the alphabet, using the vector `letters`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(group = which(name == letters))
```

### 2-) Create a auxiliar data.frame

In this alternative a create a data.frame with the variables `name` and `group`

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  left_join(
    tibble(
      name = c("a","b","c"),
      group = 1:3
    )
  )

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   name  value  group
   <chr> <chr>  <int>
 1 a     12         1
 2 b     45         2
 3 c     78         3
 4 a     asd        1
 5 b     qwe        2
 6 c     tyu        3
 7 a     zxc        1
 8 b     curced     2
 9 c     454        3
10 a     123        1
11 b     64         2
12 c     76         3
```